# Gimp 2.10.14 : drawing tools suddenly stopped to work

Tags: gimp, drawing, tools, bug

My drawing tools have stopped working and I don't understand why. Even after uninstalling and installing again, resetting the tool's presets, the problem still here on every single picture that I open or even new ones.

As you can see, the calligraphy tool is working but not the pencil, paintbrush, and the filling tool. However I can still select area and colors.

What can I do?

[image: Gimp Screenshot]

Comment: It would have been useful to see a screenshot showing the paint tool options.

Comment: You need to show the Tool Options panel.  It's probably a setting in there which is causing the problem.  My first guess would be either the tool's blending mode or opacity.

Answer (score 1):

i just reset the preset with the bottom of tool box and it actually worked

Comment: Bienvenue! Can you add a screenshot showing what you did? Typically, you can accept your own answer after some delay.